# Cannot install OpenCV in PyCharm GUI with Anaconda interpreter

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, anaconda

I wanna install OpenCV module in GUI if it is possible.
But as following pictures, the search result doesn't show opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python modules.
Why this problem happens?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please add to your question the list of repositories? you can see it clicking on "Manage Repositories" button

Comment: Thank you for your reading. I added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is just no such a package in repositories used by conda package manager.
Running `conda install opencv-python` from the system terminal will fail for the same reason.
You can install it with pip though.
Click the following button to use pip instead of conda package manager and try again:
[image]

Comment: Good explanation, tnx

Comment: Aha! There is a concept of repository, and `conda` and `pip` command use each different repositories. I got it. Thank you!

Comment: @Sergey K. Is there a way we could have done this by adding the correct repository to conda?

Comment: @Dude156 Sure, why not. Unfortunately, I don't know the right one :(
If you know which repo is needed, you can click + and then Manage Repositories in PyCharm.